# redirect to a html page of other website c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to redirect to another websites html page in my c# application when a user clicks on some button. I have written this

```
Response.Redirect("http://www.fashionunic.com/shop/wholesale-m04-dozen-chevron-laced-front-top-medium.html")
```

But it havent worked it is throwing path is not a  valid virtual path

I am calling the below method in page load

```
Response.Redirect("http://www.fashionunic.com/shop/wholesale-m04-dozen-chevron-laced-front-top-medium.html")
```

and in

```
public void Application_BeginRequest()
{
var MyUri  = Context.Request.Url;
if(MyUri.Contains("shop/wholesale") {
            var String = MyUri.ToString();            
            Context.RewritePath("http://www.fashionunic.com/shop/wholesale-m04-dozen-chevron-laced-front-top-medium.html");
}
}
```

Exception:

> Invalid path for child request '
>   http:/www.fashionunic.com/shop/wholesale-m04-dozen-chevron-laced-front-top-medium.html'.
>   A virtual path is expected.

Comment: "it havent worked" ... can you put the whole exception details, and the method where this code resides in?

Comment: *it havent worked* doesn't help anyone.. read your question and ask yourself will you be able to answer it if someone asked you the exact same question

Comment: Well for starters, are you wanting a virtual path? Are you accessing a file from the same directory?

Comment: No its from other directory

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your code, you should change 'Context.RewritePath' to 'Response.Redirect'. It should works.

Look here, it maybe useful for you: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/two-approaches-to-redirection-in-aspnet/

Also, maybe you are marketer and you are trying to promote 'fashionunic' shop :-D

Comment: Thanks I'll go through the link and by the way I'm not a marketer